How were cities administered in the Middle Byzantine Empire (641-1081)?
So I have found something about urban administration of cities in the Roman Republic and the feudal kingdoms. But how were cities administered in the Middle Byzantine Empire? Did they have Imperial governor, or only city's own government? What was the nature of said government? Could there be a city ruled by a single ruler and then another city ruled by a republican system? Were officials appointed by the Emperor, hereditary, elected, or any of the previous depending on the city? What rights and obligations did a city have towards the central government? What about areas where there were no significant urban settlements - could a group of villages gain status of a city? Was there a division of administrative, legal and judicial power? Could cities make their own laws or were governed solely according to the Imperial law?

The StackExchange format works best when there's a single question rather than eight or nine.

Please provide all citations "So I have found something..."  What is the difference between an Imperial governor and the city's own government? Why do you assume there is a single pattern/rule?  Question seems to be predicated on the notion that the MBE governance framework was designed (as in a constitutional government) rather than evolved (as in most autocratic pre-modern states, and most particularly empires).  Please document all research and provide all citations.

Does this answer your question? How were cities administered in the early Byzantine Empire?
